# Override MiKTeX-bundled Ghostscript with a separate installation

Tags: miktex, ghostscript

It looks like https://miktex.org/packages/miktex-ghostscript-bin still uses a far outdated (more than 3 years old) GPL Ghostscript for Windows. This is tremendously annoying for certain functionalities, such as transparency support in PDF.

Is there a way to have a system-wide Ghostscript intstallation override the version bundled with MiKTeX?

Comment: As it stands this is not a question

Comment: @MichaelNüsken probably best to open an issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: My point is that this site is a Q&A, and we cannot address issues in specific software bundles. For MiKTeX, only the developer (Christian Schenk) can address specifics - there is an issue tracker available for MiKTeX but it it ultimately down to Christian whether he wishes to make a change here.

Comment: @albert: Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Yet, it's another account to create...

Comment: @MichaelNüsken yes, you will have to create an account. But what do hope to achieve by asking here? That someone else opens the issue for you at the right place?

Comment: Alternatively, you could install TeXLive. The Windows version also ships with a bundled GS, and this one is up-to-date.

Comment: At https://miktex.org/ they mirror request from here. I hoped that would have an effect. And: it just appeared there on the list.
Also, I followed albert's proposal.

Comment: What was your question again?

Comment: @MichaelNüsken Would you please reword your question (title and body)? This would make it fit to this site's format. I'd suggest: How to override the MiKTeX-bundled Ghostscript with a separate, up-to-date installation.

Comment: Rewrote the question to make it on-topic.

Comment: The "reformulation" was never my question! A workaround is only a temporal solution but the problem already exists for years. So a real solution is needed.

Phrase it like this: How to convince the MiKTeX maintainers to update their installation? And that was answered.

See github [Isse 275](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/275), that seems to a more appropriate place for continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known MiKTeX issue. Its maintainer proposes to

```
set MIKTEX_PREFERMIKTEXGHOSTSCRIPT=false
```

in the Windows environment.

Source: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/218#issuecomment-761536256

Comment: See github [Isse 275](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/275), that seems to a more appropriate place for continuing this discussion.